# How can I check for an int in a variadic list?

Tags: objective-c

I've got a method that can take a variable number of arguments.

I'm using variadic commands to get the arguments and store them in an NSMutableDictionary.

The problem is, if I send an int to the method, I get a crash, because NSMutableDictionaries can't store an int.

What I want to do is make the method check if one of the arguments is an int, and if it is, turn it into an NSNumber before I put it in the dictionary.

But I can't for the life of me find out how to check for an int.

[I know one answer would be "don't send an int to the method, only send NSNumbers!"  Problem is, that places an obligation on the caller of the method that can't be determined from the method description alone.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of arguments in variadic lists cannot be checked. It has to be specified by some other way.

For instance, `NSLog()` uses the format argument to get type information: `%@` for an object, `%d` for an integer value or `%f` for a floating point value.

Comment: Not only that but you will need to be careful with type promotions. For examples, floats will always get promoted to doubles.

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across the concept [***"Type Encodings"***](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html) in Apple doc. This is done using ***@encode()*** compiler directive. Doc says that, *"When given a type specification, @encode() returns a string encoding that type"*.

So, sing ***@encode()*** and ***typeof()*** and ***strcmp()*** we can find  the type of the variable that is passed. *typeof()* returns the type of the variable. For example, *@encode(int)* returns *"i"* and consider a variable named *var* is an integer variable, then *typeof(var)* would return *int*. In this case, *@encode(int)* and *@encode(typeof(var))* would return *"i"* only. We can check for the equality of the strings using *strcmp()* method.

```
if (strcmp(@encode(typeof(variable)), @encode(int)) == 0) {

    // The varibale is an "int"
    // @encode(int) returns "i"

    // @encode(float) returns "f"
    // @encode(double) returns "d"

} else if (strcmp(@encode(typeof(variable)), @encode(NSObject *)) == 0) {

    // The varibale is an "object"
    // @encode(NSObject *) returns "@"
    // You can use anything in the place of NSObject in the above line
    // @encode(NSString *) or @encode(UIButton *) will also return "@"
}
```

There is list give for all the Objective-C type encodings. You can check for the string encodings of the other types in the above Apple doc link.

**Application of the above concept in variadic functions:** It will be *almost impossible* to use the above type encoding concept to variadic finctions with different kind of arguments, as we get each argument from va_arg() method only after specifying the type as the argument. So, we are trying to get the argument to find its type from va_arg() method which itself requires the type to return the argument. Bit annoyoing!

Comment: @Yuji:+1 - `typeof(var)` works only with variables and its value is determined at compile time. OP tries to find the type of a value stored in the stack at runtime. There is no type indication in stack.

Comment: @Yuji, Your doubt is correct. It seems, it is impossible to apply the concept to va_list ;-(

Comment: I'm using id as the variable type in my va_arg statements.  Does that change anything?

Comment: If you use your first argument as `id` or some other object type, *va_arg* excepts all the other arguments to be of object types. Combining both the object and primitive types as arguments would result in unexpected behavior.

Comment: Really! Great! Post that as an answer here. I'd like to know how to do it ;-)

Comment: I think I figured out how to do this, and it's actually relatively easy.  It's not obvious, but it's easy.  I'm using Key-Value Coding.  All I have to do is declare an instance variable, for instance an id called checkMyType, and set up accessor methods.  Then I pass the variadic item into checkMyType, and use valueForKey: to retrieve the value of checkMyType.  If checkMyType is holding an int, it will automatically get wrapped in an NSNumber as it's passed along.  I still don't know if the item was an int to start with, but no matter what I end up with an NSNumber that works in a dictionary.

Comment: I haven't actually figured it out.  I thought it was working, but it wasn't.  Gnng.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this isn't working.  I thought it was, but now I'm getting crashes I don't understand.  If I figure it out, I'll come edit this more.  Here's what I wrote before, which is wrong.  Again, this is not working:

> I think I found the answer to this: Key-Value Coding.
>
> With Key-Value Coding, I can set up an instance variable of type id,
>   and then dynamically identify the actual contents of the variable.  I
>   can put anything in it, even an int, and Key-Value methods will
>   identify it for me.  But what's even more awesome is that if I
>   retreive the contents of a variable using Key-Value Coding, and the
>   variable turns out to be an int, Key-Value Coding automatically turns
>   it into an NSNumber for me.
>
> I will attempt to demonstrate.
>
> The main thing is to set up accessor statements for the variable I
>   want to access.  So, for this example, let's say the variable is
>   called "identifyMe."
>
> ```
> //in the interface:
> @property (copy) id accessIdentifyMe;
>
> //in the implementation:
> @synthesize accessIdentifyMe = identifyMe;
> ```
>
> Now "identifyMe" is Key-Value Compliant.  We're good to go.
>
> All I have to do is take the items in the variadic list, pass them
>   into identifyMe one by one, and use Key-Value methods to identify the
>   contents.  Like so:
>
> ```
> /*...assume all the following is happening inside a loop that
> ```
>
> counts through 
>       the variadic list.  I'll call the variadic list "variadicList." 
>   First, I take 
>       the current variadic item and put it into identifyMe, declaring it
>   as type 
>       "id"*/
>       identifyMe = va_arg(variadicList, id);
>
> ```
> /*Now I use a Key-Value method to check if identifyMe holds an
> ```
>
> NSNumber.  If it 
>       holds an int, it will automatically be returned as an NSNumber,
>   you'll recall, so 
>       querying for an NSNumber is functionally the same as querying for
>   an int.
>       Outside the loop I've set up a handy boolean called foundANumber
>   in which to 
>       store the results of the query:*/
>       foundANumber = [[self valueForKey:@"identifyMe"]
>   isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]];
>
> That's given me the ability to separate the numbers from the objects. 
>   With that done, I can put the objects directly into my dictionary, and
>   put the numbers into an NSNumber before I put them in the dictionary.
>
> And what this means at the other end, when calling this method from
>   another object, is that I can call this method and put an int in the
>   parameter list and not worry about causing a crash.  Yay.

Here's the reason this isn't working: KVC isn't magic.  I thought it had some super special way of determining the type of a variable, but it doesn't.  It just looks at the type declared in the accessor methods, and it can't independently verify any more than that.  Darn.